# Can't reproduce approximately the chi-squared test value, did I misconduct?

Tags: chi-squared

I want to reproduce the chi-squared test for goodness of fit as attached below the table.

[image]

| Deposits | Actual frequency | Negative binomial frequency | Poisson frequency |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 8586 | 8584.26 | 8508.53 |
| 1 | 176 | 176.84 | 303.1 |
| 2 | 35 | 39.09 | 5.4 |
| 3 | 13 | 11.25 | 0.06 |
| 4 | 6 | 3.62 | 0 |
| 5 | 1 | 1.23 | 0 |
| 6 | 0 | 0.44 | 0 |
| 7 | 0 | 0.16 | 0 |
| 8 | 0 | 0.06 | 0 |
| 9 | 0 | 0.02 | 0 |
| 10 | 0 | 0.01 | 0 |

I tried to run the code in R and the result is the same with my manual calculation in Excel.

```
> q()
> M <- as.table(rbind(c(8586, 176, 35, 13, 6, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0),
+ c(8584.26, 176.84, 39.09, 11.25, 3.62, 1.23, 0.44, 0.16, 0.06, 0.02, 0.01)))
> (Xsq <- chisq.test(M))

        Pearson's Chi-squared test

data:  M
X-squared = 1.6568, df = 10, p-value = 0.9984

Warning message:
In chisq.test(M) : Chi-squared approximation may be incorrect
```

```
> N <- as.table(rbind(c(8586, 176, 35, 13, 6, 1),
+ c(8508.53, 303.01, 5.4, 0.06, 0, 0)))
> (Xsq2 <- chisq.test(N))

        Pearson's Chi-squared test

data:  N
X-squared = 75.536, df = 5, p-value = 7.19e-15

Warning message:
In chisq.test(N) : Chi-squared approximation may be incorrect
```

[image]

I got $\chi^2 = 1.6568$ for the negative binomial frequency and $\chi^2=75.536$ for the Poisson frequency. The values of the statistical test can't approximate the values below the table.

Have I done the correct interpretation of the $\chi^2$ equation below :

$$\chi^2=\sum^k \frac{(observed-expected)^2}{expected}$$

Or, should I just take the actual frequency as the $observed$ value and the negative binomial frequency/Poisson frequency as the $expected$ value instead? However, I have tried this method but the $\chi^2$ also didn't approximate the value below the table.

Comment: If you do not get an answer here, you could try https://stats.stackexchange.com

Comment: Suggestion: When presenting a table of numeric data in your question, it is better to use a form where your readers can copy and paste the data, rather than in a screen capture as you have done here.  You are likely to find more people who are willing to help if they don't have to re-type your numbers into their own spreadsheet or math software.  Possibilities are a MathJax matrix or a [Markdown table](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/356997/new-feature-table-support).

Comment: My guess (but I haven't tested it) is that the author may have combined some of the cells--maybe those for deposits $4$ through $10$.  If I recall correctly, we are usually advised that the count in each cell should be at least $5$ before computing the chi-square statistic.

Comment: Alright, I'll write the data so people can copy it... Sorry for inconvenience. I've tried the suggestion from @awkward to combine the frequencies which are less than 5 with actual frequency as observed value and negative binomial/Poisson frequency as the expected value , I get the $\chi^2$ for negative binomial distribution the same as the reading but not for the Poisson distribution. Many thanks.. At least now I know which step is missed.

Answer (score 0):

I have figure out the proper way to code the $\chi^2$ in R if the expected value already given.

For the negative binomial frequency :

```
> a <- c(8586, 176, 35, 13, 7)
> b <- c(8584.26, 176.84, 39.09, 11.25, 5.54)
> (Xsq3 <- chisq.test(a, y=NULL, correct = TRUE, b, rescale.p=TRUE))

        Chi-squared test for given probabilities

data:  a
X-squared = 1.0893, df = 4, p-value = 0.896
```

For the Poisson frequency I applied two ways:

```
> a <- c(8586, 176, 35, 20)
> c <- c(8508.53, 303.01, 5.4, 0.06)
> (Xsq4 <- chisq.test(a, y=NULL, correct = TRUE, c, rescale.p= TRUE))

        Chi-squared test for given probabilities

data:  a
X-squared = 6842.9, df = 3, p-value < 2.2e-16

Warning message:
In chisq.test(a, y = NULL, correct = TRUE, c, rescale.p = TRUE) :
  Chi-squared approximation may be incorrect
```

```
> a <- c(8586, 176, 55)
> c <- c(8508.53, 303.01, 5.46)
> (Xsq4 <- chisq.test(a, y=NULL, correct = TRUE, c, rescale.p= TRUE))

        Chi-squared test for given probabilities

data:  a
X-squared = 503.43, df = 2, p-value < 2.2e-16
```

I apply the suggestion from @awkward to combine the frequencies that are less than 5. If I don't combine them, R will give such a warning message. However, for the Poisson frequency it seems that the author consider the tail distribution quite important, so he kept the class distinct.